# ngbTooltip is not working with dynamically created elements

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am appending an element dynamically to a div with ngbTooltip attributes.  But tooltip is not working on hover, am I missing anything?
Here is the code,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvfn56

TIA.

Comment: Angular directives, like `ngbTooltip`, are not standard HTML. They must be processed by the Angular compiler and, therefore, they cannot be set dynamically with `innerHTML`. In general, setting content with `innerHTML` should be a last resort option. If you can, define the `div` content explicitely in the template, and use structural directives to make it dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, @ConnorsFan.  In my real application, I am using Shadow DOM slot in which I am appending contents dynamically with appendChild.  So I can't use structural directives.  Is there any other way?

Comment: I am not familiar with Shadow DOM slots but I see a few articles that talk about them in relation to Angular elements, like [this article](https://www.sahosofttutorials.com/Course/Angular7/112/).

Comment: okay. I think I have to compile the dynamic HTML string to make it work.  Do you know the angular equivalent of $compile?

Comment: I don't know if you will like the answers, but the question has been asked and answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34784778/1009922).

Comment: I tried dynamic compiling @ConnorsFan. But it's not triggering the ngbTooltip onInit method. [Here is the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvfn56-d6kaft)